# How can i make the roll button be associated with the certain video url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the 6 roll buttons to be associated with specific videos that will be able to play continuously over and over e.g. the first roll button I would like it to show the dice color yellow and the second button to show the dice color blue etc...

So far I have created the 6 buttons that when you click each of them they are playing the videos randomly. I have tried to remove the math.random and every time I do that I keep getting my videos to be blank and I'm not quite sure what approach I should take?

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default Styles"/>
    <script>

var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "How can we become more self-organised in the next sprint?";
r_text[1] = "How can we improve our productivity, increase our velocity?";
r_text[2] = "How can we get better in Transparency and Visibility of issues and challenges?";
r_text[3] = "How can our PO help us, to focus more on the sprint goal?";
r_text[4] = "How can our SM help us improve our delivery?";
r_text[5] = "How can we be more T-shaped in the next sprint?";
r_text[6] = "How should we celebrate our successes more?";
r_text[7] = "How can we reduce our cycle times?";
r_text[8] = "How can we make our daily scrum more effective?";
r_text[9] = "How can we improve our delivery flow by applying WIP Limit?";
r_text[10] = "How can we improve our collaboration?";
r_text[11] = "How can I help someone else in the next sprint?";
r_text[12] = "How can we improve our Sprint planning event?";
r_text[13] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Courage more?";
r_text[14] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Respect more?";
r_text[15] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Focus more?";
r_text[16] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Commitment more?";
r_text[17] = "How can we demonstrate Scrum Value Openness more?";
r_text[18] = "How can we make Sprint Review more effective?";
r_text[19] = "How can I help PO breakdown user stories better?";
r_text[20] = "How can we improve user story refinement?";
r_text[21] = "How did you overcome a difficult situation/challenge?";
r_text[22] = "How can we be more confident about our delivery?";
r_text[23] = "How well do you communicate with others?";
r_text[24] = "How well the team communicates with each other?";


var talk = new Array();
talk[0] = "Talk about issues in our Processes";
talk[1] = "Talk about issues in the Team behaviour";
talk[2] = "Talk about what you want your team to do more";
talk[3] = "Talk about what you want the team to stop doing";
talk[4] = "Talk about what you want the team to start doing";
talk[5] = "Tell us about something that helped you during the sprint to achieve work";
talk[6] = "Talk about something you learnt during the  previous sprint";
talk[7] = "Talk about your sprint experience through a sport's game?";
talk[8] = "Talk about your worst time during the sprint?";
talk[9] = "Talk about the biggest success during the sprint?";
talk[10] = "Talk about the major issue you faced during the sprint?";
talk[11] = "Talk about a most recent problem and how did you overcome it?";
talk[12] = "Talk about something that you feared during sprint planning however it was not mentioned at that time?";
talk[13] = "Talk about someone in the team you inspire from and why? Don’t mention the name";


var what = new Array();
what[0] = "What can Scrum Master to improve our Scrum Events?";
what[1] = "What made you feel happy?";
what[2] = "What made you feel unhappy?";
what[3] = "What was your key observations?";
what[4] = "What minor issues that slowed you down";
what[5] = "What can we change to make the biggest leap ahead?";
what[6] = "What did you see happening by someone you think everyone should try?";
what[7] = "What advice would you give to your team members? And why?";
what[8] = "What has been the biggest challenge so far?";
what[9] = "Which problems came up most frequently?";
what[10] = "What has been the most difficult situation in the sprint?";
what[11] = "What obstacles do you anticipate and how you think that can be addressed?";
what[12] = "What can we do to improve our Sprint planning event?";
what[13] = "What would you do differently in the next Sprint?";
what[14] = "What would you like to avoid in the next Sprint?";
what[15] = "What can we do to make our Scrum events more fun?";
what[16] = "What can we do to get full trust of our key stakeholders?";
what[17] = "What support do we need from our PO?";
what[18] = "What support do we need from our SM?";
what[19] = "What support do we need from our Stakeholders? Sponsors/External…";
what[20] = "Describe the most difficult challenge team faced? What could have been done to avoid/fix it?";
what[21] = "What do you wish you could change in the way of working?";
what[22] = "What support do you need to achieve your sprint goal?";
what[23] = "What areas of your team WOW would you like to improve/change?";
what[24] = "What routinely gets in your way?";
what[25] = "What would you like your PO to do more and why?";
what[26] = "What would you like your SM to do less and why?";


var morefun = new Array();
morefun[0] = "Describe your feeling by naming a Movie. Explain";
morefun[1] = "Describe your feeling by singing a Song. Explain";
morefun[2] = "Describe your feeling by hands/body gestures.";
morefun[3] = "Describe your sprint experience by telling a story?";
morefun[4] = "Who's someone you admire in the team?";
morefun[5] = "What are your favourite quotes?";
morefun[6] = "Who had the most influence on you growing up?";
morefun[7] = "What advise can you give us?";
morefun[8] = "If you could go back in time, what would you like to change? Work or Life";
morefun[9] = "Show your best dance moves?";
morefun[10] = "Draw an emoji to show how you feel about the sprint";
morefun[11] = "How would you have handled Brexit?";
morefun[12] = "If you would become the Prime Minister what would be your top agenda items?";
morefun[13] = "Do an animal impression (please don’t tell)";
morefun[14] = "Do an impression of a Cartoon character (please don’t tell)";
morefun[15] = "If you had 30 hours a day, how would you use the extra time?";
morefun[16] = "If you could swap your role with another team member, who would it be?";
morefun[17] = "Do a Bhangra dance?";
morefun[18] = "Ask anyone in the team to perform an act? Movie character, cartoon character etc…";
morefun[19] = "Stand on one leg and jump 5 times, or ask your PO to do this act?";
morefun[20] = "Ask your SM or PO to perform a celebration move, or could decide to do it yourself.";


var showshare = new Array();
showshare[0] = "Share your most recent learning experience?";
showshare[1] = "Share any productivity improvement tip with the team?";
showshare[2] = "Share your best moment during the Sprint and why?";
showshare[3] = "if you could change one thing about yourself what would you choose?";
showshare[4] = "If you could eliminate one thing from your daily routine what would it be?";
showshare[5] = "If you could become an expert in any area instantly, what would it be?";
showshare[6] = "Share a tip to help others improve their ways of working?";


var goingtodo = new Array();
goingtodo[0] = "Do I/we understand the Product Vision? Team and I";
goingtodo[1] = "Do I/we understand the Sprint Goal? Why, Value, Benefits. Team and I";
goingtodo[2] = "Do I/we communicate well within the team? Team and I";
goingtodo[3] = "Do I/we communicate well outside the team? Team and I";
goingtodo[4] = "Do I/we collaborate with team and outside team? Team and I";
goingtodo[5] = "Do I/we openly raise issues and challenges? Team and I";
goingtodo[6] = "Do I/we openly talk about impediments?";
goingtodo[7] = "Do we ask each other for help and support?";



var videos = [{
    id: 1,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-1.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return r_text[Math.floor(r_text.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-2.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return what[Math.floor(what.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-3.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return talk[Math.floor(talk.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-4.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return morefun[Math.floor(morefun.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Dice-3d-5.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return showshare[Math.floor(showshare.length*Math.random())];
    }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: "http://ebeessolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Red-dice.mp4?autoplay=1",
    text: function(){
      return goingtodo[Math.floor(goingtodo.length*Math.random())];
    }
  }

];

var currentTimeout = null;
window.onload = function() {
  function rollVideo(numberRand) {




 //   let playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
 //   if (document.querySelector("iframe") !== null) {
 //     document.querySelector("iframe").remove();
 //   }
//    let player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    let randomVideoUrl = videos[numberRand].url;

    let myv = document.getElementById("myvideo") ;
     myv.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);




//    player.setAttribute("width", "640");
//    player.setAttribute("height", "390");
//    player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
//    playerDiv.appendChild(player);
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";

    clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
    currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text();
    }, 3000);
  }


  document.getElementById("btn-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);
  document.getElementById("btn2-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);
  document.getElementById("btn3-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);
  document.getElementById("btn4-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);
  document.getElementById("btn5-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);
  document.getElementById("btn6-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);


  function startRoll() {
    let currentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    rollVideo(currentNumber);
  }
};





    </script>
</head>

<div align="center">
      <button id="btn-roll">Roll</button>
      <button id="btn2-roll">Roll</button>
      <button id="btn3-roll">Roll</button>
      <button id="btn4-roll">Roll</button>
      <button id="btn5-roll">Roll</button>
      <button id="btn6-roll">Roll</button>


<div id="test">
    <video id="myvideo" width="740" height="390" autoplay="">

    </video>    

</div>
<div id="text"></div>
</html>




     <! –– and the comment closes with ––>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `if-else` statements in your function?

Comment: @King11 No, since I am not quite sure how I would be able to use that in this code at the moment since if I do that I will need to make other changes which im not familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a simple `if-else` statement. I gathered the `id` of the clicked button in your `startRoll` function and you can do your functionality from there. Each button corresponds to a specific video based on what number you assign the variable. This by far isn't the best way to achieve this, but it should get you what you want. Hopefully this helps.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/321hdwrk/1/